# Get default value from another table based on column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default-value, calculated-columns

In the following, the first row are headings and all the values are | delimited.

I have a table called **MemberInfo**, as follows:

```
ColumnName|Value
AccountCode|FredsDiscounts
Id|1
Name|Joe Bloggs
Address|1 Puddle lane, PL99 9PL
SignatureRequired|0
PetRegistered|NULL
BrochureType|Post
MembershipType|NULL
```

Note: **MemberInfo** has only two columns, which are; *ColumnName* and *Value*.

I have another table called **DefaultValues**, as follows:

```
AccountCode|Name|Address|SignatureRequired|PetRegistered|BrochureType|MembershipType
FredsDiscounts|Unknown|Unknown|1|0|Email|Normal
JillsSupers|Unknown|Unknown|1|0|Post|Super
GreggsFurniture|Unknown|Unknown|1|0|Email|None
JeremySwift|Unknown|Unknown|1|0|Telephone|Normal
```

Note: **DefaultValues** has seven columns, which are; *AccountCode*, *Name*, *Address*, *SignatureRequired*, *PetRegistered*, *BrochureType* and *MembershipType*.

For the values in **MemberInfo** that are NULL, which in this case are *PetRegistered* and *MembershipType* I want the values from the corresponding column in **DefaultValues** to take their place.

Which row to use should be chosen based on the **AccountCode**.

The desired result would be, as follows:

```
AccountCode|FredsDiscounts
ColumnName|Value
Id|1
Name|Joe Bloggs
Address|1 Puddle lane, PL99 9PL
SignatureRequired|0
PetRegistered|0
BrochureType|Post
MembershipType|Normal
```

I don't know how to reference a column without knowing its name beforehand.

The method I currently employ is as follows:

```
DECLARE
    @AccountCode VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FredsDiscounts'

SELECT 
    MemberInfo.ColumnName, 
    CASE WHEN MemberInfo.Value IS NOT NULL THEN MemberInfo.Value ELSE Defaults.[DefaultValue] END AS Value 
FROM
    MemberInfo
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        (SELECT 'AccountCode' AS [ColumnName], @AccountCode AS [DefaultValue]) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'Name' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[Name] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'Address' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[Address] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'SignatureRequired' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[SignatureRequired] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'PetRegistered' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[PetRegistered] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'BrochureType' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[BrochureType] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) UNION
        (SELECT TOP 1 'MembershipType' AS [ColumnName], DefaultValues.[MembershipType] AS [DefaultValue] FROM DefaultValues WHERE DefaultValues.Accountcode = @AccountCode) 
    ) AS Defaults ON [Defaults].[ColumnName] = MemberInfo.[ColumnName]
```

...not very elegant.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You would use a left join to both tables and then either ISNULL or COALESCE.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to type all of this out but will demonstrate the basic concept. You simply need to use a left join here.

```
select mi.AccountCode
    , PetRegistered = ISNULL(mi.PetRegistered, d.PetRegistered)
from MemberInfo mi
left join DefaultValues d on d.AccountCode = mi.AccountCode
```

---EDIT---

Since the real issue here is that you are working with an EAV you are going to have to write a LOT more code than you would with a more normalized table structure. The following should work for you.

```
declare @AccountCode VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FredsDiscounts';

with MemInfo as
(
    select AccountCode = max(case when ColumnName = 'AccountCode' then Value end)
        , Id = max(case when ColumnName = 'Id' then Value end)
        , Name = max(case when ColumnName = 'Name' then Value end)
        , Address = max(case when ColumnName = 'Address' then Value end)
        , SignatureRequired = max(case when ColumnName = 'SignatureRequired' then Value end)
        , PetRegistered = max(case when ColumnName = 'PetRegistered' then Value end)
        , BrochureType = max(case when ColumnName = 'BrochureType' then Value end)
        , MembershipType = max(case when ColumnName = 'MembershipType' then Value end)
    from MemberInfo mi
    where AccountCode = @AccountCode
)

select mi.AccountCode
    , mi.Id
    , Name = isnull(mi.Name, dv.Name)
    , Address = isnull(mi.Address, dv.Address)
    , SignatureRequired = isnull(mi.SignatureRequired, dv.SignatureRequired)
    , PetRegistered = isnull(mi.PetRegistered, dv.PetRegistered)
    , BrochureType = isnull(mi.BrochureType, dv.BrochureType)
    , MembershipType = isnull(mi.MembershipType, dv.MembershipType)
from MemInfo mi
inner join DefaultValues dv on dv.AccountCode = mi.AccountCode
```

Comment: Well if your post had those details in a format like a create table this would be a LOT easier to decipher. You are working with an anti-pattern known as EAV (entity attribute value). The concept is the same but your query is going to be infinitely more complicated because you have to first do a dynamic pivot to turn that EAV into a usable table, then you will be able to do a left join to the DefaultValues table.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my question, which includes this solution as an example of what I do not want to do.

Comment: The top 1 multiple query solution you have is pretty ugly for sure. If you post that MemberInfo as a table I will show how you can do it.